# Integral domain ${\mathbf Z}[\alpha] = \{a + b\alpha\ |\ a,\ b \in {\mathbf Z}\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

**Exercise:** Show that the smallest subdomain of complex numbers containing the element $\alpha=\frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2}$ is ${\mathbf Z}[\alpha] = \{a + b\alpha\ |\ a,\ b \in {\mathbf Z}\}$.

I thought I could first show that $\mathbf{Z}[\alpha]$ is indeed an integral domain by verifying all axioms (that's  easy) and then I would show that if there's a smaller domain $N$, $x \in \mathbf{Z}[\alpha]$ exists such that $x \notin N$. This $x = a + b\alpha$ for some $a,\ b \in \mathbf{Z}$ (as it is in $\mathbf{Z}[\alpha]$). But from the axioms it follows that for integral domain $N$, we have $\mathbf{Z} \in N$ and $\alpha \in N$, so $a + b\alpha \in N$, a contradiction.

It's easy to show that ${\mathbf Z}[\alpha]$ is a commutative ring, but I have trouble showing that $a,\ b \in {\mathbf Z}[\alpha],\ a,b \neq 0 \implies ab \neq 0$.

Have I chosen a sensible way or is there a better approach?

Thanks.

Comment: "being integral domain" i.e. $a,b \neq 0 \Rightarrow ab \neq 0$ is actually the ine thing zou don't need to prove - it hold for general complex nombers, so it holds for the elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ especially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subring of a field is automatically an integral domain: zero divisors in it would be zero divisors in the field.

The set $\{a+b\alpha:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is surely contained in any subring of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $\alpha$. So you just have to prove it's a subring.

Closure under addition and opposite is clear; moreover $0=0+0\alpha$ and $1=1+0\alpha$. For closure under multiplication:
$$
(a+b\alpha)(c+d\alpha)=ac+(bc+ad)\alpha+bd\alpha^2
$$
But
$$
\alpha^2=\frac{5+1-2\sqrt{5}}{4}=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}=1-\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}
=1-\alpha
$$
so you can conclude.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's what I meant.

Comment: Well, that's how far I got (except I got $\alpha^2 = \alpha + 1$). But how can I tell that for nonzero $a,b$, $ab$ is nonzero? What is the essence of "subring of field is *automatically* integral domain"?

Comment: @DavidČepelík I added a couple of words. If $a,b\ne0$ in the subring, then they are still element of the field, so $ab\ne0$.

Comment: @DavidČepelík The $2$ was wrong, but $\alpha^2=1-\alpha$, not $1+\alpha$.

Comment: Right... Too late. Will fix it now.

Comment: One more thing: how can I be sure that such a set is contained in *every* subring of $\mathbf{C}$? Especially, how do I know that $\mathbf{Z}$ is contained in it? Is it because $1$ is in every subring, so that all natural numbers are in it, all opposites are in it and $0$ is in it?

Comment: @DavidČepelík Since $1$ is in any subring, all its multiples are; since $\alpha$ must be in the subring, all its multiples must too; any sum of elements of a subring belongs to the subring. Put these together and you get that $a+b\alpha$ ($a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$) must belong to any subring containing $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks for all help, @egreg!